# Amplify Access Control Issue: Unable to Login After Setting Up Amplify Serve with CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify

I've deployed a web application on AWS Amplify, and I've implemented password protection using Amplify's built-in access control features. Initially, everything worked smoothly, and I could log in and access the application using the default Amplify URL.

However, the issue arose when I set up CloudFront with a custom domain name to serve the application. Now, when I attempt to log in and access the app using the custom domain, it repeatedly prompts me to enter my username and password. I'm confident that I'm entering the correct credentials.

The problem seems to be specific to the setup with CloudFront, as the authentication works as expected with the default Amplify URL. I'm seeking assistance in resolving this access control issue when using the custom domain.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution for this issue. You'll need to attach the origin request policy in CloudFront that forwards all headers except "Host" header in the viewer request. There is already a managed policy with this configuration called "AllViewerExceptHostHeader," which you can use.

To do this, follow these steps:

1. Select the CloudFront distribution entry you want to edit.
2. Navigate to the "Behaviors" tab and select the entry to which you want to attach the origin request policy (in my case, it's the default entry).
3. Click on "Edit" and go to the "Cache Key and Origin Requests" section.
4. Under "Origin Request Policy," select the "AllViewerExceptHostHeader" from the dropdown.
5. Once done, click on "Save Changes."

If you're unable to locate the policy, you can create a custom one. To do this, ensure that in the Origin request settings, under the "Headers" section, you select 'All viewer headers except' and explicitly exclude 'Host'.